# Realizar web scraping en excel VBA para actualizar lineup mlb

Tags: excel, web, vba, macros

La cuestión es que estoy creando una base de datos en excel tomando datos de la "MLB" para que luego todo quede organizado de manera automatizada. Estoy presentando el siguiente problema con una de las macros del libro.

Al ejecutar la macros y extraer los datos de la web se copian agrupados en una sola celda.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Estoy necesitado que estos datos queden organizados de la siguiente manera:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Este es el código que estoy utilizando:**

```
   Sub Actualizar_lineups1()
'(declarar o reservar memoria para) nuestras variables.
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer 'variable de objeto especial que representa el IE
Dim Ele As HTMLLinkElement 'variable de objeto especial para un <a> (enlace)
Dim y As Integer   '  variable entera que usaremos como contador
Dim result As String 'variable de cadena que mantendrá nuestro enlace de resultado
'iniciando una nueva instancia de Internet Explorer y asignándola a objIE
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
'hacer visible el navegador IE (Falso permitiría que IE se ejecute en  segundo plano)
objIE.Visible = True
 'navegar por IE a esta página web
objIE.navigate "https://www.mlb.com/starting-lineups/2019-05-02"
 'Espera aquí unos segundos mientras el navegador está ocupado.
 Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
'El primer resultado de búsqueda irá en la fila 1.
y = 1
For Each Ele In objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("starting-lineups__matchup ")
 '...obtener el texto dentro del elemento e imprimirlo en la hoja en la columna A
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & y).Value = Ele.innerText
Debug.Print Ele.innerText
 'incrementa nuestro contador de filas, por lo que el siguiente resultado va abajo
y = y + 1
'Repite varias veces el # de ele que tenemos en la colección.
Next
'cierra el navegador
objIE.Quit
'salir de nuestra subrutina
End Sub
```

> De anticipado muchísimas gracias

Answer (score 2):

No sabría cómo hacerlo directamente desde la web, pero para que te salga como quieres podrías hacer esto:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Actualizar_lineups1()
    '(declarar o reservar memoria para) nuestras variables.
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer 'variable de objeto especial que representa el IE
    Dim Ele As HTMLLinkElement 'variable de objeto especial para un <a> (enlace)
    Dim y As Integer   '  variable entera que usaremos como contador
    Dim result As String 'variable de cadena que mantendrá nuestro enlace de resultado
    Dim ws As Worksheet 'declara siempre variables de hoja y/o libros
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'dale el valor para poder utilizarlo luego
    'iniciando una nueva instancia de Internet Explorer y asignándola a objIE
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    'hacer visible el navegador IE (Falso permitiría que IE se ejecute en  segundo plano)
    objIE.Visible = True
     'navegar por IE a esta página web
    objIE.navigate "https://www.mlb.com/starting-lineups/2019-05-02"
     'Espera aquí unos segundos mientras el navegador está ocupado.
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    'El primer resultado de búsqueda irá en la fila 1.
    y = 1
    Dim arr, i As Long, LastRow As Long

    For Each Ele In objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("starting-lineups__matchup ")
     '...obtener el texto dentro del elemento e imprimirlo en la hoja en la columna A
        With ws
            .Range("A" & y).Value = Ele.innerText
            'Aquí va el código para separar los datos de esa celda
            arr = Split(.Range("A" & y), Chr(10))
            .Range("A" & y).ClearContents
            For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
                LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                .Cells(LastRow, 1) = arr(i)
            Next i
        End With
        Debug.Print Ele.innerText
     'incrementa nuestro contador de filas, por lo que el siguiente resultado va abajo
        y = y + 1
    'Repite varias veces el # de ele que tenemos en la colección.
    Next
    'cierra el navegador
    objIE.Quit
    'salir de nuestra subrutina

End Sub
```

Comment: Por favor disculpe mi torpeza, intente ejecutar el código que usted me dio pero da error de compilación dice "no se puede encontrar el proyecto o la biblioteca"  y me subraya  "Chr"  de esta parte del codigo Chr(110)). a conticunacion codigo con el nombre del libro en el que lo ejecutare. he intentado cambiar la cantidad de caracteres a 256 pero aun  nada Dim arr, i As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'aquí pon la hoja en la que trabaja la macro
    arr = Split(.Range("A1"), Chr(110))
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        .Cells(i, 1) = arr(i)
    Next i
End With

Comment: es `Chr(10)`, no `Chr(110)`

Comment: Lo hice Chr(10) el problema es que al tener los dos códigos en el mismo libro de ejecución presenta este error, si ejecuto el código que usted me dio en otro libro sin ningún otro código funciona pero al ejecutarlo en el mismo libro da este error, que debo hacer

Comment: @YuniorCruz he actualizado mi respuesta para implementar mi código en el tuyo.